# Custom Catalog URL Rewrites deleted after reindex

Tags: url-rewrite, reindex

This is not a new question, *but.* nowhere I'm able to find the answer to this question.

When I reindex Catalog URL Rewrites, my custom rewrites get deleted/overwritten(???). Below is an image of the settings, what is wrong with these settings?

Magento = 1.8.0.0 *but* it was also occurring with the previous version.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a fix for this problem?

Comment: 0 down vote
 

I have the same problem. Has anybody tried the solution above? Thanks OZ.asked by by user24167

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is a commonly encountered problem with magento URL rewriting system.

A short term solution can be to create the required system URL (using category or cms page) and then edit it.

System URLs are not deleted upon re-indexing.

Comment: So, just to make sure, if I change the type option to system instead of custom (as it is now) my problem will be over?

Comment: Yes. That should solve the problem.

Comment: strange though, one would expect that "custom" would be the thing they don't erase. In a few days I'll check it out and post the results here. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution would be to set the redirect method of the regarding system rewrite (ID path "category/YOUR_ID", target path "catalog/category/view/id/YOUR_ID") to "permanent (301)" and then create a custom rewrite rule with the request path "catalog/category/view/id/YOUR_ID" to fit your needs. Saw it [here](http://www.entroducing.com/view/redirect-magento-category-to-a-url) and translated it into German [here](http://www.econcess.de/blog/10-onlineshop-erstellung-magento/109-magento-redirect-weiterleitung-von-kategorien-und-reindizierung).

**Survives reindexing**, tested in Magento CE 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think It has something to do with the `ID Path` you provided. Id paths like `category/*` and `product/*` are considered to be category/product rewrites. When reindexing these rewrites are either deleted or overwritten by the real rewrites for that category or product.
Try changing the `ID Path` to some random value like this `1f129c42de5e4f043cbd88ff6360486f` then reindex, and see if the error reproduces.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for the answer. But this is not it.
Reason: When i try a random ID Path the link goes to (in this case) `/catalog/category/view/s/customer-service/id/21/`

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me absolutely bonkers until I figured out a nice little work-around.

I create my new object (in my case it was a category for the top nav I go to URL Rewrite and note the ID Path of the new category I delete the system generated URL Rewrite I create a custom Rewrite specifying the ID Path of the deleted object, The request path, and then the path to the desired URL I then go to phpmyadmin > core_url_rewrite and find my newly created custom Rewrite I change the store_id to 0 (not changing anything else) I then go back to Magento and run a reindex. This creates a new system generated Rewrite with a higher url_rewrite_id (see in phpmyadmin > core_url_rewrite table) I then create my page with the desired path Reindex / flush caches and presto.. my top nav now has a menu item to my new page.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this same problem.
Magento does not support "custom url rewrites" in admin panel for many reasons.

**You have 3 options:** *Easiest to Hardest*

1. Utilize a Static block
2. RewriteEngine On. Add your exception (`.htaccess`)
3. Interpret & Modify (`index.php`)

Any other method will revert on **Reindex**